# Simple PHP query works on one page, blows up on another

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this exact code on two pages, and on one of the two it blows up.  Both pages have the exact same user/pass/host/db links (same header), and the query returns a record if I print the $command and paste into Sequel Pro.

Here is the query:

```
$command = "SELECT ID,Location,OriginalLocationID FROM locations WHERE FloorID='".$_SESSION['FloorID']."' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
echo $command;
$query = mysql_query($command);
while($results = mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    $_SESSION['LocationID']=$results[0];
    $_SESSION['LocationName']=$results[1];
    $_SESSION['OriginalLocationName']=$results[2];
}
```

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

As a note, the SESSION['FloorID'] is set when you click the link, so that's not blank or broken.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong, or why it would work on one page and not another?

Also - yes I've Googled, it isn't an empty error or syntax or anything, because as I mentioned it works perfectly on another page.

Comment: `$_SESSION['FloorID']` is available in which link? We see none here. Did you call `session_start()` at the beginning of this script?

Comment: `echo mysql_error()` to see the actual cause of the error.

Comment: What does `echo $command;` display?

Comment: You have to click on a list of links to get to this page, so it's set before you get to this page.  And yes I do have session_start at the top.  The $command prints exactly as it should, and when I copy it into Sequel Pro I get the desired record.

Comment: @Lauren then you'll have to consult `mysql_error()` to find out what it doesn't like.

Comment: Oh my gosh.  The database connect hadn't been called - Michael, thanks for posting that.  Can you post an answer and I'll approve it?  (The suggestion to call mysql_error...)

Comment: PHP does not query, and SQL can not blow up. What is your question?

Comment: @hakre Oh stop.  No need to be rude.  Michael pointed me in the right direction, thank you.

Comment: Lauren, please read the FAQ, that's not rude at all.

Comment: hakre, I didn't say that PHP queried, I said that the query returned a record in SQL to indicate that there wasn't an issue with the query itself.  I also said that my code blew up, not SQL.  It's certainly rude to post snarky comments aimed at making another user feel stupid.  My question obviously wasn't completely confusing because two users attempted to help before you posted.  Perhaps you could keep in mind that if someone asks a "stupid" question it may not be because they are stupid, but because they've been looking at something too long and might not see the obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource

This indicates the the query itself failed, which may happen because of invalid syntax or because the database connection itself has not been established.

You must perform error handling before calling `mysql_fetch_row()`, and upon failure, use `mysql_error()` to identify the error cause.

```
$query = mysql_query($command);
if ($query)
{
  while($results = mysql_fetch_row($query))
  {
      $_SESSION['LocationID']=$results[0];
      $_SESSION['LocationName']=$results[1];
      $_SESSION['OriginalLocationName']=$results[2];
  }
}
else echo mysql_error();
```